# Adding Claim for OWIN ClaimsIdentity.AddClaim() from database. ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, owin, claims-based-identity

I am testing a .NET 4.7 Web Api project using Entity Framework and looking at adding claims for user to restrict access to certain web api's

Every example/tutorial I have come across (code example below) gives this type of example on adding new Identity.AddClaim().

Adding new claims via if conditions for multiple users of varying roles is of course not the way so I'm expected the use of a database table to fetch role data for the context.UserName and then to make a new claim with that data e.g.

```
 Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, [database.user.role]));
```

However I'm yet to come across a recommendation for this approach.

Is this the recommended approach and if so is there is specific table schema that should be adhered to for user roles?

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
        if (context.UserName == "admin" && context.Password == "admin")
        {
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "admin"));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("username", "admin"));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Sourav Mondal"));
            context.Validated(identity);
        }
        else if (context.UserName == "user" && context.Password == "user")
        {
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "user"));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("username", "user"));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Suresh Sha"));
            context.Validated(identity);
        }
        else
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "Provided username and password is incorrect");
            return;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through several suggestions here and there and the best suggestion i found was to start a new project with individual user accounts setting checked in Wep API 2 project set up wizard

[image]

This allows database tables creation inline with Microsoft out the box roles and identity services

and then you can assign roles with RoleManager and fetch user roles with userManager with which you can create claims within GrantResourceOwnerCredentials method

Comment: You could have added a comment to my answer in which you acknowledge that the suggestion was indeed what you were looking for.

Comment: sorry wasnt aware that this removes your comments when answering your own question.